Bash convert last character to lower
I'm trying to convert the last character of in a variable to lower.
MY_STRING="THE_NAME_UPPER_A"

I want to change it by THE_NAME_UPPER_a. I've try this
MY_NEW_STRING="${MY_STRING,,A}"

but it changes all A to a, I just want to change the last one.

You mean you're trying to convert the last character of a string to lower?

If I understand you correctly you could use tr:
## Your string
MY_STRING="THE_NAME_UPPER_A"

## Everything but the last character
prefix="${MY_STRING:0:$((${#MY_STRING}-1))}"

## Getting the last character
lastChar="${MY_STRING: -1}"

## Change last character to lowercase
lastCharLow="$(echo "$lastChar" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"

## Combine it all and echo
echo "${prefix}${lastCharLow}"


eliminate the dual subshells required for $(echo ... | tr ...) with lastCharLow="${lastChar,,}"

prefix="${MY_STRING:0:$((${#MY_STRING}-1))}" could be written as just prefix="${MY_STRING::-1}".

In plain bash, without using an external command:
my_string="THE_NAME_UPPER_A"

lastchar=${my_string: -1}
my_new_string=${my_string:: -1}${lastchar,}

echo "$my_new_string"

